# Is this a safe way to free memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, eigen

I have a member variable called `neuronLayers` which is of type `std::vector<Eigen::RowVectorXf*>` and another called `weights` of type `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf*>`.

As part of a forward propagation function, I need to multiply values from these two vectors and keep a pointer to that value. I've already made sure the sizes of the dimensions of values I'm multiplying match, so there's no concern there.

I came up with this:

```cpp
for (unsigned i = 1; i < this->topology.size(); i++) {
    delete this->neuronLayers[i];
    this->neuronLayers[i] = new Eigen::RowVectorXf((*this->neuronLayers[i - 1]) * (*this->weights[i - 1]));
}
```

Unfortunately, memory management is a weak point of mine, so I might be missing something blindingly obvious. I'm just conscious that carelessly creating `new` objects can lead to memory leaks.

When I ask if this is safe, what I want to know is if this could cause to memory leak, or somehow lead to some other memory error? If it could, how could I modify that code snippet to fix this issue?

**Edit:**
`neuronLayers` is used elsewhere with other code that expects it to be a vector of `Eigen::RowVectorXf*` pointers rather than a vector of `Eigen::RowVectorXf` objects. The snippet shown doesn't show this.

Comment: Why use pointers at all? Use `std::vector<Eigen::RowVectorXf>` and `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf>` instead, then you won't have anything to `new` or `delete`.  But, if you must, then consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers, then you don't have to worry about `delete` manually. And you can use `std::make_unique()` to avoid `new`.

Comment: Why are you even using `new` and `delete` to begin with?! Can't you do `std::vector<Eigen::RowVectorXf>`, and so on?

Comment: If you cannot hold these objects by value, at least use `shared_ptr<RowVectorXf>`

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: Note: `std::shared_ptr` has not-insignificant overhead to manage the sharing and is best reserved for cases where the object legitimately has two or more owners with a stake in the lifetime of the object. If this isn't the case for your code, use `std::unique_ptr` and have one owner.

Comment: This part by itself is fine.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to create a new object rather than change the value of the existing object?

Comment: Your code appears not to delete the last element in the vectors. Why do you loop from `i=1` instead of `i=0` and index `[i-1]` instead of `[i]`?

Comment: @doug the last element is deleted. I'm deleting element i rather than i-1. Element 0 is skipped here, but that's a special case so it gets dealt with before this loop starts.

Comment: Got it. Ignore my comment. I read your code too quickly.

Answer (score 8):

A better option would be to not use any dynamic allocations at all.  You don't need `new` and `delete` in this case, just get rid of the pointers and hold actual objects in your `vector`s instead, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<Eigen::RowVectorXf> neuronLayers;
std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXf> weights;
...
for (unsigned i = 1; i < topology.size(); i++) {
    neuronLayers[i] = Eigen::RowVectorXf(neuronLayers[i - 1] * weights[i - 1]);
}
```

Comment: If I had written the whole thing from scratch, I probably wouldn't have used pointers. But other parts of the code that I did not write expect a vector of pointers. Trying to go along with that code seemed like a better idea than trying to replace it.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaChukwuenweniwe Then you'll need to figure out *why* that code uses a vector of points. It may be, for example, that multiple pointers to the object are kept and, in that case, just deleting it and allocating a new object is asking for trouble.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's a good point. In this case, I don't think it will be an issue, but I wasn't thinking about that before. Thanks for pointing it out.